# jq: sort object values

Tags: json, jq

I want to sort this data structure by the object keys (easy with `-S` and sort the object values (the arrays) by the 'foo' property.

I can sort them with

```
jq -S '
  . as $in
  | keys[]
  | . as $k
  | $in[$k] | sort_by(.foo)
    ' < test.json
```

... but that loses the keys.

I've tried variations of adding   `| { "\($k)": . }`, but then I end up with a list of objects instead of one object.  I also tried variations of adding to $in (same problem) or using `$in = $in * { ... }`, but that gives me syntax errors.

The one solution I did find was to just have the separate objects and then pipe it into `jq -s add`, but ... I really wanted it to work the other way. :-)

Test data below:

```
{
    "": [
        { "foo": "d" },
        { "foo": "g" },
        { "foo": "f" }
    ],
    "c": [
        { "foo": "abc" },
        { "foo": "def" }
    ],
    "e": [
        { "foo": "xyz" },
        { "foo": "def" }
    ],
    "ab": [
        { "foo": "def" },
        { "foo": "abc" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
jq -S '.[] |= sort_by(.foo)'
```

Output

```
{
  "": [
    {
      "foo": "d"
    },
    {
      "foo": "f"
    },
    {
      "foo": "g"
    }
  ],
  "ab": [
    {
      "foo": "abc"
    },
    {
      "foo": "def"
    }
  ],
  "c": [
    {
      "foo": "abc"
    },
    {
      "foo": "def"
    }
  ],
  "e": [
    {
      "foo": "def"
    },
    {
      "foo": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: nice, that's shorter than the other I got suggested (posted separately). It's confusing to me that `.[] |` in your solution doesn't "lose data".  I guess the `jq` data model isn't clear to me at all and I still think too much of it like a normal programming language where I have to return the data as I need it.

Comment: The manual entry on the [update-assignment operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Assignment) will help, I think.

Answer (score 0):

@user197693 had a great answer. A suggestion I got in a private message elsewhere was to use

```
jq -S 'with_entries(.value |= sort_by(.foo))'
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason using the `-S` command-line option is not a satisfactory option, you can also perform the by-key sort using the `to_entries | sort_by(.key) | from_entries` idiom. So a complete solution to the problem would be:

```
.[] |= sort_by(.foo)
| to_entries | sort_by(.key) | from_entries
```